# Pre-define work items for inherited process and auto create it in Azure Boards

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to pre-define some commonly used work items in Azure DevOps using the inherited process and populate the Azure Boards automatically with these work items when a new project is created using this process?

E.g., there are commonly used work items in most of our projects like "User module", "Login module", etc. Is it possible to set this by default somewhere so that when I create a new project, these work items are already there on Azure Boards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to set this by default somewhere so that when I create a new project, these work items are already there on Azure Boards?

I am afraid there is no such way to do this at this moment.

According to the document [Customize your work tracking experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-work?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops), we could to know:

> Customizations you make occur at one of three levels:
>
> - **Team assets or tools:** Each team can customize or configure their    specific tools, for details,see About teams and Agile tools
> - **Project level:** **Add or modify work item types, data fields, backlog    levels, and other objects shared across teams**
> - **Object level:** Grant or restrict access to work tracking tools, which    includes setting permissions for objects and the project and 
>     assigning users or groups to specific access levels.

For the project level, we could custom the work item types, data fields, backlog levels and so on, which are all components or attributes for workitem not the workitem this whole. What you want is an custom instance based on process, this is closer to the template not process.

To achieve it, just like Shayki said, you could use Azure DevOps Rest API to write the scripts to create those workitems and add it to the Azure Boards after you create the project, like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433167/create-work-items-in-vsts-with-rest-api-using-powershell).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, for the insights and providing a link to an example use of rest API. I have also created a feature request for implementing the said functionality [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/673850/ability-to-pre-define-work-items-for-inherited-pro.html) I hope it will be picked up.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal, That`s be great! I subscribed it, will check the feedback. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

No, this feature not exist in Azure DevOps, you can create a [Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) for this.

As workaround, you can use [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops) and write a small script that create those work item, when you create a new project just run the script.