# How to integrate in house system with azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

The in-house system produce tickets. Instead of creating work item manually in azure devops, i need it to automatically create work item from ticket in the in-house system.

Comment: You can create work items with API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 0):

That`s depends from the in-house system. In most cases, this situation is resolved by the custom application that uses [Azure DevOps Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). The common flow:

1. Find tickets to publish. Add some property to highlight tickets for Azure DevOps and property with Azure DevOps Work Item Id. Then search tickets without Work Item Id
2. Register a [new work item on Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)
3. Update Azure DevOps Work Item Id on the source ticket in your in-house system.

You can use [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) or [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433167/create-work-items-in-vsts-with-rest-api-using-powershell) or any another language.